# How can I set the stride of an Image properly?

Tags: image-processing, bitmap, bitmapdata

While converting from `double[,]` to `Bitmap`,

```
Bitmap image = ImageDataConverter.ToBitmap(new double[,]  
                                    {   
                                    { .11, .11, .11, }, 
                                    { .11, .11, .11, }, 
                                    { .11, .11, .11, }, 
                                    });
```

the routine gives

```
data.Stride == 4
```

Where does this value come from?

Since the `double[,]` is `3x3`, stride should be `5`. Right?

How can I fix this not only for this one, but also for any dimension?

**Relevant Source Code**

```
public class ImageDataConverter
{
    public static Bitmap ToBitmap(double[,] input)
    {
        int width = input.GetLength(0);
        int height = input.GetLength(1);

        Bitmap output = Grayscale.CreateGrayscaleImage(width, height);

        BitmapData data = output.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height),
                                            ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
                                            output.PixelFormat);            

        int pixelSize = System.Drawing.Image.GetPixelFormatSize(output.PixelFormat) / 8;

        int offset = data.Stride - width * pixelSize;

        double Min = 0.0;
        double Max = 255.0;

        unsafe
        {
            byte* address = (byte*)data.Scan0.ToPointer();

            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    double v = 255 * (input[x, y] - Min) / (Max - Min);

                    byte value = unchecked((byte)v);

                    for (int c = 0; c < pixelSize; c++, address++)
                    {
                        *address = value;
                    }
                }

                address += offset;
            }
        }

        output.UnlockBits(data);

        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how you arrived at 5.

> The stride is the width of a single row of pixels (a scan line), rounded up to a four-byte boundary.

[Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.stride(v=vs.110).aspx)

Since it's 3x3, 3 rounded up to four-byte boundary is 4.

Comment: This is not 4 byte. This is 4 bit.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "4 byte" or "4 bit."  If you are using [AForge CreateGrayscaleImage](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/657b935b-9e20-6a2b-d0ae-5e59e23e17df.htm) it is using 8 bits per pixel for 256 (2^8) shades of gray, meaning one byte per pixel and three bytes per row, rounded up to 4.

Comment: what should be the color depth?

Comment: Why are you asking me?  That depends on your requirements.  The code you posted creates an image with an 8-bit grayscale.